How to calculate cumulative percentage return on a changing base
I am evaluating the cumulative % return on a trading strategy that requires constant rebalance / scaling, but find it difficult to arrive at an intuitive and sensible method.
Daily PnL & % Return
This is easy to derive. Say there are two legs, one long and one short. Assume 100% margin on both legs and it makes sense to use the net notional exposure as our "capital deployed" or as the demonitor for % return (assume I receive SOFR on the short leg). Let's say on date 12-20-2024 the long leg notional is \$2,000,000 and short leg is \$1,000,000, and the dollar pnl for this date is \$10,000. Then the daily % pnl for this date should be
$$
\text{daily pnl}=\frac{\text{daily \\\$ pnl}}{\text{net exposure}}=\frac{10,000}{2,000,000-1,000,000}=1\%
$$
Cumulative % Return
This is where it gets tricky as I face two major challenges. One is that I would rebalance / scale the positions constantly, resulting in jumps in net exposure; another is the net exposure of two legs change constantly themselves. Below is one hypothetical example where I find it hard to calculate cumulative return on:



Date
Net Exposure
Daily Dollar PnL
Daily % Return
Cumulative % Return




12/1/2024
\$1,000,000
\$100,000
10.00%
10.00%


12/2/2024
\$5,000,000
-\$10,000
-0.20%
9.78%


12/3/2024
\$10,000,000
-\$100,000
-1.00%
8.68%



Obviously this method's cumulative % return doesn't make sense as on day 3 -- cumulative return is 8.68% while the \$ PnL is negative -\$10,000. This is because the same daily \$ PnL would affect differently on changing net exposure base.
Since this strategy's nature is to jump and scale up / down on net notional exposure (contrary to most other strategies where base notional stays more stable), is there any way to measure cumulative return properly?

You might consider MoM ("multiple of money") or MOIC ("Multiple on Invested Capital")  type of measures where you keep track of the dollars gained or lost, and compare them to your net investment in the strategy (your contributions minus your withdrawals over the years if any). It is not a true  "return" though.

Hi: I'm not familar with nbbo's measures but here's another approximation where the exposure is looked at as the price and one calculates the cumulative log return.  It comes out close to zero which kind of makes sense given the numbers.  approx = log(990000/1000000) * log(4900000/5000000) * log(9900000/10000000)
